# I am getting Cannot find symbol error while using dependencies.getEdgeSet()

Tags: java, dependencies, stanford-nlp

I am working with Collapsed dependencies using Stanford CoreNLP.

I am getting

> cannot find Symbol. Symbol:method getEdgeSet()

error while typing the following code:

```
Set<SemanticGraphEdge> edge_set1 = dependencies.getEdgeSet();
```

No other errors are found. I have already imported

```
 edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphEdge;
```

Why does it happen so?

Comment: Add the `dependencies` declaration into your post + the `import` line for the `dependencies` type.

Comment: `SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
            Set<SemanticGraphEdge> edge_set1 = dependencies.getEdgeSet();` @engineer

Comment: `import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedDependenciesAnnotation;`

Answer (score 0):

The type of `dependencies` is [`SemanticGraph`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html) which doesn't have the method `getEdgeSet()`.

In the first paragraph in the documentation you can see:

> There is **no mechanism for returning all edges at once** (eg edgeSet()). This is intentional. Use edgeIterable() to iterate over the edges if necessary.

See [`getAllEdges(IndexedWord gov, IndexedWord dep)`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html#getAllEdges-edu.stanford.nlp.ling.IndexedWord-edu.stanford.nlp.ling.IndexedWord-) and [`edgeIterable()`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html#edgeIterable--) instead.